# How can I get specific cells specific Worksheet of an workbook which is linked as Hyperlink in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, cell, worksheet

I have a cell range which can contain hyperlinks to other excel datas.
[Hyperlink in a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH7Wc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH7Wc.png)

I need to get a specific cell in a specific worksheet of that hyperlink.
I just do not know how to reach that cell.

Does someone know the syntax for  this problem?
Is this even possible?

I did not know how to get that specific cell, so I tried pulling the worksheet at first like this:
AktiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=c.Hyperlinks.Application.Worksheets(1)

The best option would be that I do not even have to pull the worksheet, but as I said i do not have a clue.

Answer to the comment:

I am in a workbook, where you can find in the A1 the value "C:\Users\z0\Downloads\GG.xlsm", which is the path of the a closed workbook.
I try to get as example the A1 cell of Sheet1 of the closed workbook and paste the value to lets say B1 in the workbook where you can also find the path.

I already tried this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = wb.Worksheets(1)
Dim cell As Range: Set cell = sh.Range("A1:A1000")
Dim pth As String
Dim qafWb As Workbook

pth = Replace(Range("A1").Value, "\", "/")
qafWb = Workbooks(pth)
sh.Range("B2") = qafWb.Worksheets(1).Range("G13")
```

The compiler is saying that the variable qafWb does contain "nothing"

I hope that I was able to express my needs :)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Write Formula Using 'Hyper' Cell (VBA)

- It is assumed that the formula in the 'hyper' cell is something like

  ```
  =HYPERLINK("C:\Users\z0\Downloads\GG.xlsm","Whatever")
  ```

```vb
Sub WriteFormulaUsingHyperCell()
   
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_CELL As String = "A1"
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_HYPER_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_FORMULA_CELL As String = "B1"
    Const NOT_FOUND_STRING As String = "Not found"
    
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim hStr As String: hStr = dws.Range(DST_HYPER_CELL).Formula
    Dim hParts() As String: hParts = Split(hStr, """")
    If UBound(hParts) < 1 Then GoTo WriteResult ' no double quotes
    
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = hParts(1)
    Dim Position As Long: Position = InStrRev(sFilePath, "\")
    If Position = 0 Then GoTo WriteResult ' no backslashes
                
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = Left(sFilePath, Position)
    Dim sFileName As String:
    sFileName = Right(sFilePath, Len(sFilePath) - Position)
    
    Dim dFormula As String: dFormula = "='" & sFolderPath & "[" & sFileName _
        & "]" & SRC_SHEET_NAME & "'!" & SRC_CELL
    
    IsSuccess = True
    
    'Debug.Print sFilePath
    'Debug.Print sFileName
    'Debug.Print dFormula
    
WriteResult:
    
    With dws.Range(DST_FORMULA_CELL)
        If IsSuccess Then
            .Formula = dFormula
        Else
            .Value = NOT_FOUND_STRING
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a file name in your worksheet in cell `A1` with the path e.g. `C:\Users\z0\Downloads\GG.xlsm`
In `E1` the name of the sheet e.g. `Sheet1`, in `F1` the address of the cell e.g. `A1`
In `A4` you want to read this value.
You can use a macro like this:

```
Sub ReadFromFile()
    Dim adr As String, path As String, filename As String
    Dim shname As String, celladr As String
    adr = Range("A1").Value
    path = Left(adr, InStrRev(adr, "\"))
    filename = Mid(adr, InStrRev(adr, "\") + 1)
    shname = Range("E1").Value
    celladr = Range("F1").Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("A4").Formula = "='" & path & "[" & filename & "]" & shname & "'!" & celladr
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```